# Dictionary container, that find the value also if the key is not completely correct

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers

I need a c++ memory dictionary container, that get a key, and return a value any way.
That is, if the key doesn't exist in the 'keys list', it will find the most similar key, and give the value.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Thank for the comments.

More details:
For Simplicity, let's start with numeric key. If the key is within 200 distance from the key, get it.

Comment: You'll have to handle the 'find the most similar key if the key doesn't exist' logic yourself. There's no structure in the standard library (or anywhere, that I know of) that's gonna do that for you.

Comment: What is a most similar key? Usually one assumes that a key is unique and is associated with some value. Unless you are talking about multimaps etc.

Comment: Do you want your special container to do some sort of trial and error if the key does not exist?(like swap around cases in a string, etc) Or are you asking for a way to have a multiple keys that map to the same value in the map.

Comment: @Dave and others, So, I need to write a method myself, OK. I assume that i need all keys in sorted list for that, no? How to do this?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the keys to be sorted. This depends on your best match criteria.

Comment: It all really depends on what you mean by similar. Are we talking about strings where a certain percent of characters are the same? Numbers where it falls within a certain range of the original? "Similar" and "Sort of" and "Almost" will almost always be illusions in a program: Carefully crafted data to approximate an almost.

Comment: @yoni: We need more information. If you tell us the type of objects you are using as keys, maybe we can help you. Please give that information. Without that, we can only state the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something called [locality-sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing), and you'll need to write a little bit of code on top of it (just a tiny bit, I promise. One extra word).

First, you need to use `std::map` and not `std::unordered_map` or any other hash table - it *has* to be a tree or other ordered data structure.

Your key would be the locality-sensitive hash, which has the behavior of hashing similar inputs to close outputs. So the hash of AAA and the hash of AAB would be closer together than the hash of AAA and CCC. The value would be whatever you want it to be.

To retrieve the "nearest match", you just need to use the `std::map::lower_bound` (or `std::map::upper_bound`) to get the nearest value to any given input from the map.

So your code would look like this

```
std::map<unsigned int, some_struct> mymap;
for(;;;)
{
   mymap[locale_sensitive_hash(some_struct(some random value))] = some_struct(some random value)
}

//Now find the object we have that is nearest to some_struct(AAA)
unsigned int this_hash = locale_sensitive_hash(some_struct(AAA));
some_struct nearest_object = mymap.lower_bound(this_hash);
```

Done and done.

Some Notes:

This is assuming a non-numberic key. Numbers are already "locale-sensitive hashes" of themselves, i.e. if `H(n)` is `n`, the difference between `H(n)` and `H(n')` is directly proportional to the difference between inputs `n` and `n'`. In that case, `lower_bound` is the only thing you need, and you don't need the extra hashing step.

You can extend this method very easily to do things like specify a maximum distance between objects. This will depend on the locale sensitive hash you're using and how it signifies the distance between two hashes for two given inputs, but generally just compare `H(n)` and `H(n')` before returning the `nearest_struct` (with `nearest_struct` being `n'`).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a multimap...

```
T& get(int key)
{
    // use a multimap as storage
    static multimap<int, T> m;

    multimap<int, T>::iterator best;

    // search for key within 200
    for (auto it = m.lower_bound(key-200); it != m.upper_bound(key+200); ++it)
        if (best)
            // if multiple matches use the closest one to the key
            best = (abs(it->first-key) < abs(best->first-key) ? it : best);
        else
            best = it;

    // if none found, insert new entry
    if (!best)
         best = m.insert(key, T());

    return best->second;
}
```

Another way which is a bit faster, but more messy, is to use an unordered_map and two levels of keys...

```
T& get(int key)
{
    struct KeyValue
    {
        int key;
        T value;
    };

    static unordered_map<int, vector<KeyValue>> m;

    vector<KeyValue>::iterator best;

    int b = key/200;
    int a = b - 1;
    int c = b + 1;

    // function to search bucket for a key...
    auto ms = [&](int bucket)
    {
        for (auto it = m[bucket].begin(); it != m[bucket].end(); ++it)
            if (abs(it->key - key) <= 200)
            {
                if (best)
                    best = (abs(it->key - key) < abs(best->key - key));
                else
                    best = it;
            }
    };

    ms(a);
    ms(b);
    ms(c);

    if (!best)
        best = m[key/200].push_back({key, T()});

    return best->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is probably going to be writing your own container class that extends `std::map` via composition.

Hold a `std::map` as a member and forward whatever needed functions and typedefs.

Make sure to implement your "trial and error" logic with at least the following functions:

- `count`
- `find`
- `operator[]`
- `at`

Comment: That is what he needs to do, but what of the similarity itself? Depending on the type of object, this could be much simpler.